# Get rid of horizontal autoscrolling on Eclipse (Windows 7)

Tags: windows, eclipse, windows-7

Package Explorer is scrolling horizontally when the mouse pointer is near the edges. Did anyone manage to get rid of this annoying feature?

I'm running Oracle Workshop for Weblogic 10.3 (Eclipse 3.3.3) on Windows 7. My guess is that autoscrolling is windows' fault.

Comment: Windows 7 (or any other version of Windows) do not automatically scroll anything based solely on the position of the cursor.

Comment: I've found some people suggesting that the scrolling doesn't happen in [compatibility mode for Windows XP](http://metova.com/display/PUBTECH/Eclipse+Tips#EclipseTips-PreventthePackageExplorerfromautoscrollingleftandright). So, that's may be windows' fault.

Comment: That might be a red herring. Windows does no autoscrolling based only on cursor position. All the programs I've used do not autoscroll just because I move the cursor to some edge. It's something that is implemented by the application.

Answer (score 1):

I also don´t think it is an Eclipse feature. Check your mouse driver in the control panel if you find such an option there.